# Alguém sabe qual erro no Script do INNER JOIN que faz com que o valor se repita por toda tabela?

Tags: mysql, sql

Vez ou outra me pego batendo cabeça ao pensar o por que o meu `INNER JOIN` repete valores por toda coluna, mesmo sem correspondência entre as tabelas pela coluna selecionada.

```
SELECT notas_fiscais.NUMERO, tabela_de_clientes.NOME, tabela_de_clientes.CPF
FROM 
    notas_fiscais INNER JOIN tabela_de_clientes
    ON notas_fiscais.CPF = tabela_de_clientes.CPF;
```

[tabela trazendo todos os números das notas fiscais e repetindo o cliente e seu CPF por toda coluna.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TLGd.png)

Comment: Não publique imagens , publique em texto. Qual a repetição ? Publique a estrutura das tabelas.

Answer (score -2):

Tenta assim! O `left outer join` traz apenas resultados que se equivalem.

```
SELECT notas_fiscais.NUMERO, tabela_de_clientes.NOME, tabela_de_clientes.CPF
FROM notas_fiscais 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tabela_de_clientes ON notas_fiscais.CPF = tabela_de_clientes.CPF;
```

Comment: Retornou o mesmo resultado :S 
Verifiquei aqui e essas notas fiscais são sim correspondentes a essa pessoa, mas o script está ignorando todas as outras combinações para trazer mais clientes.